# proof of lemma 10-8, In functional analysis book of Rudin page 232

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis

In functional analysis book of Rudin page 232, proof of lemma 10-8 We have a function $ h_r(\lambda)= \frac{r^2 g(\lambda)}{z^2(2r-g(\lambda))} , \lambda \in \mathbb{C} $ and $ g(\lambda)$  is an entire function on $\mathbb{C}$. Then  $ h_r(\lambda)$  is analytic in $ \lbrace \lambda :|\lambda|< 2r \rbrace $. My question is that why  $ h_r(\lambda)$ is analytic in $ \lambda=0$ ?  Please help me. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proof starts with

> Since $f$ has no zero, there is an entire function $g$ such that $f = \exp\{g\},\; g(0) = g'(0) = 0$, and $\operatorname{Re} [g(\lambda)] \leq \lvert\lambda\rvert$.

The condition $g(0) = g'(0) = 0$ - where $g'(0) = 0$ follows from $f'(0) = 0$, and $g(0) = 0$ is by choice ($f(0) = 1$) - ensures that

$$h_r(\lambda) = \frac{r^2g(\lambda)}{\lambda^2 [2r - g(\lambda)]}$$

is analytic in $\lambda = 0$, since the power series expansion of $g$ starts $a_2\lambda^2 + a_3\lambda^3 + \dotsb$.